# Tornado is enough for Websocket in serverside?

Tags: websocket, tornado

sorry for my dumb question, [now that i got that i must use Javascript to use Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685776/why-javascript-is-important-for-websocket), this is client-side, but what about Serverside, why do i find people talking about RabbitMQ, Stomp, SocketIO, Tornadio

in the Tornado example, no one of them exists, so i said that Tornado is enough, but i found that people use them even with Tornado, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483440/using-tornado-with-pika-for-asynchronous-queue-monitoring) and [here](http://www.lonelycode.com/2011/11/27/use-tornadio-to-create-a-websockets-rabbitmq-bridge/).

So what do i use? and for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Tornado is a web-server and it supports web-sockets. Other things in your post are not webservers.

RabbitMQ is a message queue service, it's used to communicate between different services on the server

STOMP is a [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol) to work with message queues.

Socket.IO is a framework that allows you to use websockets easily. But it requires Node.JS server on the server side. Socket.IO provides you some fallbacks if browser do not support WS protocol. Tornadio is a port of Socket.IO to Tornado. So you can use the same client framework (in web-browser) but on server-side you use Tornado instead of NodeJS.

So Tornado is enough for websockets. But if you'd like to create more complex apps you'll have to use other tools for other tasks. From your list - you can use Tornadio to deal with legacy browsers and RabbitMQ for interprocess communication on your server

Comment: thank you! am sorry but am a beginner, so what do you mean by RabbitMQ functionnalities, do you mean synchronisations? (avoid 2nd message sent to be the first one? )

Comment: Imagine that you have several Tornado servers. And if one of the server receives a particular request you want all servers to take some action. This could be achieved with RabbitMQ

Comment: so it's like a load balancer but for websockets? kind of nginx for websocket?

Comment: No, it's completely different thing. It's a message service. It allows you to send/receive messages between your applications. You can read about rabbitmq use cases on their site http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#messaging-patterns

Comment: ah, i see (blurry :p ) i'll stick right now with tornado and with time when i get complexity, i'll be ready for RabbitMQ ;) thank you again :)